# HTML get elements by attribute-value JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am looking for a method like `document.getElementsByClassName()`, but just for attributes, that would also mean that `document.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "testclass")` would have the same output as `document.getElementsByClassName("testclass")`.

It is not that easy since you cannot just add a function like this

```
document.getElementsByAttributeValue = function(){....};
```

because it has to work for `document.getElementById("foo").getElementsByAttributeValue(...)` as well.

Needless to say, that I don't want a JQuery solution because there is no need for a giant library for just one function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function I created and the implementation looks like this:

```
Node.prototype.getElementsByAttributeValue = function(attribute, value){
    var dom = this.all || this.getElementsByTagName("*");
    var match = new Array();
    for (var i in dom) {
        if ((typeof dom[i]) === "object"){
            if (dom[i].getAttribute(attribute) === value){
                match.push(dom[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return match;
};
```

I wanted the function to work within every html element and in the html document as well, so I added the function to the parent class of all html subclasses, the Node class.

There is a nice visualisation of [JavaScript objects](http://krook.org/jsdom/overview-tree.html).

With `this.all || this.getElementsByTagName("*")` I took all the html elements within the object which called the function. Then I looped through all the elements I took and checked if they had the right attribute values and if they had, I pushed them into the `match` array

Comment: No need. You could just do `document.querySelectorAll("*[foo='bar']")` or  as a substitute for `getElementsByClassName`, it would be `document.querySelectorAll(".some_class")`.

Answer (score -4):

You can use **JQuery** to easily get all the elements with a particular class as follows:

```
$('[class~="d1"]')
```

This will select the elements with class containing `d1`

Check **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M6vts/)**

For more: Read **[JQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**

Comment: i wonder why i wrote that i do not want any jquery